# json_encode with Date formatted as Microsoft's built-in JSON Date format

Tags: php, json

I need to format json so that the RecordDate is in the following format:

```
{
  "RecordDate":"\/Date(1558037543000)\/",
}
```

It needs to have the "/Date(" in the beginning and the ")/" at the end of the RecordDate field.

I have tried the following:

```
$data = array(
        'RecordDate' => '\/Date('.(time()*1000).')\/'
    );
print_r(json_encode($data));
```

This results in:

```
{"RecordDate":"\\\/Date(1558039222000)\\\/"}
```

Which it too many slashes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just remove the backslashes from your string

Comment: @msg that worked, if you want to submit that as an answer I can make it as correct.

Comment: Please mark as accepted if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` will do that for you unless you include the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option.  This is normally a pain but helps you:

```
$data = array(
    'RecordDate' => '/Date('.(time()*1000).')/'
);
```

Yields:

```
{"RecordDate":"\/Date(1558040292000)\/"}
```